# Background Threads in Horizontally Scaled Application

Tags: sql, locking, horizontal-scaling

The current situation is that I have an application that scales horizontally with one SQL database. Periodically, a background process is ran but I only want one invocation of this background process running at a time. I have tried to accomplish this by using a database row and locking but I am stuck. The requirement is that only one batch job should have successfully completed per day.

Currently I have a table called lock which has three columns: timestamp, lock_id, status. Status is an enum that has three values 0 = not running, 1 = running, 2 = completed.

The issue is that if a batch job fails and status is equal to 0, How can I make sure that only one background process will retry. How do I guarantee that only one background process is running in the retry scenario?

In an ideal world, I would like to do a SELECT statement that checks for the STATUS in the locking table, if status is = 0 meaning not running then start the background job and change status to 1 = running. However, if all horizontally scaled processes do this at the same time, is it guaranteed that only one is executed?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to look into row locking from your application language.  Speaking of which, what is your app language?

Comment: the application language is java. Is there any documentation that you can point me too?

Comment: And also please tell us which database you are using.

Comment: I am using jpa so the db can be any sql db, depending on my landscape

Comment: A good read: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the reason I crossed off any locking from application level because the application is scaled horizontally, so they have no notion of each other

Comment: Yeah...but you have a single logical database, right?

Comment: yes I have single logical database

Comment: Then you should be able to use locking.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what if jpa is not an option in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180604/discussion-between-ryancw-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: In an ideal world, I would like to do a SELECT statement that checks for the STATUS in the locking table, if status is = 0 meaning not running then start the background job and change status to 1 = running
However, if all horizontally scaled processes do this at the same time, is it guaranteed that only one is executed?

Comment: Each thread can start, and then try to get a pessimistic write lock on the record which logically records whether the task has run.  This should be robust to multiple threads, because the DB will ensure that only one thread can get the lock.  Once a thread gets the lock, it will either see that the background task has _not_ been run, in which case it will run it.  Otherwise, if the task has been run, it will just release the lock and move on.